# Unlink tempnam throws error "Resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: php

I want to unlink (delete) my temporary file but php throws the error :

**Warning Error: unlink(*"my file path"*\Temp\TMPAF91.tmp): Resource temporarily unavailable in [*"my file path"*\myscript.php, line *"number"*]**

```
$tmpfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'zipfile');

file_put_contents($tmpfile, $content);

$zip = new ZipArchive;

if ($zip->open($tmpfile) === true) {
// my code in here to extract the $content of the $tmpfile

  $zip->close();
} 



unlink($tmpfile);
```

I'm not sure what's happening here. The ZipArchive is closed so surely I should be allowed to unlink it.

Comment: Maybe use `tmpfile()` instead. It deletes it automatically when the file is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error **only occurs on my Windows** machine (ver. 10 in a Mamp setup).

On my Linux server (distr. Debian Jessie). This works fine.

It also works fine on my Mac (Catalina in a Mamp setup).

Comment: This doesn't really answer how to solve the problem, unless the answer is "don't use Windows"

Comment: True, however the most important thing is that it works on my Linux prodution server.

Comment: But answers are supposed to be helpful to future readers of the question.